# Do native speakers pronounce 's' for the word 'corps'?

Tags: pronunciation, singular-vs-plural

My dictionary lists the pronunciation of **corps** as [kɔːʳ], [kɔrz]. So, I am wondering if native speakers really pronounce the s sound?

Comment: @user3169, I thought it could be as simple as a yes-or-no question. it's the dictionary from my phone. I assume it's pronounced as [kɔːʳ] and [kɔrz] is for plural. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Corps* is normatively pronounced with the sound [z] in its plural form, but not in its singular form. *Corps* and *core* are homophones.

In a rhotic accent, *corps* is pronounced as [kɔr] or [kor] in the singular and [kɔrz] or [korz] in the plural. (It has the same rhotic vowel as the word *force*; there is variation between accents in the quality of this vowel and in whether or not it is identical to the rhotic vowel in the word *north*.)

In a non-rhotic accent, *corps* is pronounced as [kɔː] in the singular when it comes before a word that starts with a consonant. It may be pronounced as [kɔːr] when it comes before a word that starts with a vowel, depending on how connected the two words are in speech. (The transcription "[kɔːʳ]" is a shorthand for "[kɔː] or [kɔːr], depending on the context".) It is pronounced as [kɔːz] in the plural, with no [r] sound.

(All of these are broad, not narrow transcriptions: a number of phonetic details are left out. E.g. phonetically, the vowel in a non-rhotic pronunciation may be closer to IPA cardinal 7, [oː], than to IPA cardinal 6.)